round especifico no me funciona
Tengo este código
$montoAPlazos = $cobro->montoTotal-$cobro->enganche;
$cobro->montoAbonoAcordado = ($cobro->montoAbonoAcordado == null || $cobro->montoAbonoAcordado == 0) ? 1  : $cobro->montoAbonoAcordado;

$numeroDeAbonosTotales = ceil ($montoAPlazos / $cobro->montoAbonoAcordado);
**$abonosPagados =  round($cobro->totalPagadoEnAbonos / $cobro->montoAbonoAcordado);**

Pero cuando quiero usar round ($cobro->totalPagadoEnAbonos / $cobro->montoAbonoAcordado, 2);
Me sale error de servidor

Tuve un problema similar, sin embargo no se si sea tu caso, te recomiendo validar que efectivamente los datos que le estas pasando sean numericos y tambien valida que no sean null, puedes validarlo con un if sencillo como este
$totalPagadoEnAbonos = isset($cobro->totalPagadoEnAbonos) ? (float)$cobro->totalPagadoEnAbonos : 0;
$montoAbonoAcordado = isset($cobro->montoAbonoAcordado) ? (float)$cobro->montoAbonoAcordado : 1;

$abonosPagados = $montoAbonoAcordado != 0 ? round($totalPagadoEnAbonos / $montoAbonoAcordado, 2) : 0;

